# Using 'on' with any social media platform

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, prepositions

I normally use '*on*' with mentioned site whereas I would like to know the main reason behind it.
I am wondering that should I always use **'on'** with related sites?

To put it more clearly,

> I saw your message **on** [ Internet | Facebook | Twitter | LinkedIn | and so on].
>
> I wrote you another comment **on** [ Internet | Facebook | Twitter | LinkedIn | and so on].

How about **'in'**?, would **'in'** be used for the same purpose?

Comment: Also: `on TV, on the radio`

Comment: @helix this is quite common when we talk about something *on air/broadcasting*. Radio, TV, Internet -for these all, we use *on*. As in, *when this episode will go on air?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky (+1) but being a mouse potato, I'll try my best for this!

We prefer using *on* when it is all about the site or the platform or for such matter even the portal. It's bigger. You see something **on** the Internet and so the sites on it (not just restricted to social media). I read that **on** the BBC Website.

On the other hand, when you write or read something within some block, you use *in*. You always write your message *in* your email and you see someone's message *in* your inbox. It's within that particular frame, block or whatever you say.

As a **general** rule, *on* is for some surface and *in* is for something inside. With a little adjustment, we can make this out. **On the website** and **in the email**.

**Additional but maybe, a useful note:** There could be change *in* the website. However, that's from a webmaster's view. That's again because when the change happens, it happens within the frame provided (Say WordPress or HTML). One may say... *There is a change (to be done) **in** our homepage -put this element there.*

On the other hand, if the visitors are talking about a change, for them, it's the change *on* the website. Because again, what I said, for them, it's just happening over the surface! One may say ... *I see the change **on** this website. The element which was here is here now...*

Answer (score 2):

As your question title suggests, the phrases refer to a social media *platform*.  Things are always placed *on* a platform, not *in* it.

The use of platform comes from the use of the word in the software world to describe a mechanism for supporting other work.

Specifically, a software platform is a package of programs that may be used to build other systems.  It is different from a software application.